# How to check if a item is the first item in a list

Tags: python, list

I am trying to read a dat file and extract certain information from the dat file.

My code looks like this:

```
datContent = [i.strip().split() for i in open("data.dat").readlines()]
positions = []
myItem = 'ST'
# write it as a new CSV file
for list in datContent:
     if myItem in list:
         positions.append(list)
```

I would like to check whether an item is the first item in the list and i want the two list below that. How do I do that?

Comment: Not relevant, but **please please please** don't do `for i in open("data.dat").readlines()` just do `for i in open("data.dat")`

Comment: `if myItem in datContent[0]` ?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga, why i cant do it?

Comment: Maybe `datContent[0]` is instance of `str`. So I think `if myItem == datContent[0]` will work.

Comment: @lakesh, You can, but it's highly ineffective. You are creating a list beforehand to iterate over which you can avoid by directly iterating over the file pointer. (think about some million lines file)

Comment: @Iakesh `readlines()` will read all lines at once. It is inefficient for memory. According to [PEP234](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0234/#file-iterators), you can iterate with the file object itself.

Comment: i want the two list below that ==> how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if  you want the second next list after a list has the first item `myItem` you can use:

```
[s for f, s in zip(datContent, datContent[2:]) if f[0] == myItem]
```

example:

```
datContent = [['ST', '1', '2', '3'], ['1', '5', '3'],['2', '6', '3'],['ST', '2', '4'], ['ST', '2', '2'],['2', '6', '3']]
myItem = 'ST'

[s for f, s in zip(datContent, datContent[2:]) if f[0] == myItem]
```

output:

```
[['2', '6', '3'], ['2', '6', '3']]
```

you can have a look over [zip](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) built-in function

Comment: how to get the second list after the item is found?

Comment: the `for` loop will do the job?

Comment: i need the second list after the item the list is found.

Comment: full second list or ? just also the first item ?

Comment: @lakesh an example will really help

Comment: @lakesh for this list `[['ST', '1', '2', '3'], ['1', '5', '3'],  ['ST', '2', '4'], ['ST', '2', '2']]` what is your expected result ?

Comment: for this list [['ST', '1', '2', '3'], ['1', '5', '3'],['2', '6', '3'],['ST', '2', '4'], ['ST', '2', '2'],['2', '6', '3']], the expected result is ['2', '6', '3'], ['2', '6', '3']

Comment: @lakesh check  now my answer